# Use get_post_type(); outside of the loop in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am running a function within functions.php to pre-populate an acf field. I need to set a variable which will change depending on which post type. When I run `get_post_type();` it does not work. I have tried many variations such as:

```
get_post_type($post->ID);

$id = get_queried_object_id();
$this_is_post_type = get_post_type($post->$id);
```

I have also used this wordpress function to no avail:

```
function get_post_type( $post = null ) {
    $post = get_post( $post );
    if ( $post ) {
        return $post->post_type;
    }
 
    return false;
}
```

Can anybody help me get the post type and store it within a variable I can use please? I am out of ideas. If I use get_post_type within the template files it works fine, it is only at the global level - outside of the loop - that it doesn't.

Comment: Did you try `get_post_type(get_queried_object_id())`? Also, in PHP, it is very rare and more often than not a bug for multiple `$` to exist when chaining with `->`

Comment: easiest fix is, in your function use global $post and then $post->post_type

Comment: Thank you. Angel - could you please write how that would be written to set $this_is_post_type as a variable for $post->post_type when using global $post? Thank you for your help

Comment: @Andy2021, did you try what I wrote?

Comment: Thank you - yes I did, I couldn't git it to work. I had tried a version similar to that before posting.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "didn't work"? Please know that not everything is a "post", there's also taxonomies, archives, and users. Can you try `var_dump(get_queried_object())` to see what is in there? If it isn't a `WP_Post` object then `get_post_type()` does not apply.

Comment: I tried the var_dump and the output was NULL. I tried this on default wp pages and cpt's but the output was always null. If I use get_post_type() in the php controller file say single-news.php then this does work and output correctly. It just doesn't work when used in functions.php

Comment: My next guess is that you are using it too early then. The majority of WordPress functions should be invoked _after_ certain hooks have been fired. Are you in an action or a filter?

Comment: No not within an action or a filter. I've tried it at the top and bottom of functions.php. I also have a class file for my theme, I have tried it in there but still just get the output of NULL.

Comment: When you put code into functions.php that isn't in a hook, you are saying that **every** request must run that code. That means your normal frontend stuff, but also AJAX requests, CLI requests, cron tasks and **admin** requests. **Every** request. Unless you are building some type of logger or security sub-system or similar, this is almost definitely **not** what you want. Instead, you need to determine _when_ you want that code to run, and then we can find a hook to use. So can you explain the _when_ portion, remembering all of the types of possible requests.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that's really helpful. I need the function to run first really as it's job is to pre-set a tax for a post. For example, if I create a `news` post, the acf tax field for 'post type' needs to be set as 'news'. Then a new `story` post will need the acf tax field set to 'story' etc. 

This code works perfectly to pre-set the acf field. This code pre-sets all tax fields to `news` which has the ID of '3':

Comment: `add_filter('acf/load_field/key=field_62b1c53ac1a88', 'my_acf_load_field');
function my_acf_load_field( $field ) {
    $field['default_value'] = 3;
    $field['disabled'] = true;
    return $field;
}`

The reason for determining post type is, I want to remove the tax id of **3** and instead set a variable say **post_tax** then set an if statement to say if post type = news set post_tax = 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, you are in fact inside of a filter so you should be able to access what you need. However, because you are also targeting *new* things, not all functions will behave as you expect, specifically `get_queried_object()` and similar, and this is a case where the `global $post` is probably the best way.

I ran this through a WordPress site that I have locally and it worked as expected. I'll leave the logic of the interior parts up to you.

```
add_filter(
    'acf/load_field/key=field_62b1c53ac1a88',
    function ($field) {

        global $post;

        // This should always be true because you are targeting a very specific
        // key, however better safe than sorry.
        if ($post instanceof \WP_Post) {

            // Your logic here
            if ('news' === $post->post_type) {
                $field['default_value'] = 3;
                $field['disabled'] = true;
            }

        }

        // Always return something, no matter what
        return $field;
    }
);
```

Comment: I've implemented this today and it worked perfectly :) thank you so much for your help